# Drag and Drop Actionscript Game with a multiple levels and a Home Button

Tags: actionscript

I am making a Drag and Drop Actionscript game with multiple levels and a home button, and I have the levels dragging and dropping to specific target sites, but when I click the home button the items that were dragged stay on the screen. I added removeChild but it only worked for 1 level and when you click onto another level it stops working.

the code that I have is:
**Page 1**

```
stop()


    home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_home);    
    btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_btn1);
    btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_btn2);
    btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_btn3);



function click_home(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1);
    removeChild (Qld);
    removeChild (Nsw);
    removeChild (Sa);
    removeChild (Wa);
    removeChild (Nt);
    removeChild (Vic);
    removeChild (Tas); 
    removeChild (Butter1);
    removeChild (Butter2);
    removeChild (Butter3);
    removeChild (Butter4);
    removeChild (Butter5);
    removeChild (Dog);
    removeChild (Cat);
    removeChild (Squeek);
}

function click_btn1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(5);
}
function click_btn2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(10);
}
function click_btn3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(15);

}
```

**Page 2**

```
    var objectoriginalX:Number;
var objectoriginalY:Number;

buttonMode = true;
Qld.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Qld.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
Nsw.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Nsw.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
Sa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Sa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
Nt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Nt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
Wa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Wa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
Vic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Vic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
Tas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Tas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
Tas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Tas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);


function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.startDrag(true);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    objectoriginalX = event.target.x;
    objectoriginalY = event.target.y;
}

function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.stopDrag();
    var matchingTargetName:String = "target" + event.target.name;
    var matchingTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(matchingTargetName);
    if (event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == matchingTarget){
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = matchingTarget.x;
        event.target.y = matchingTarget.y;
    } else {
        event.target.x = objectoriginalX;
        event.target.y = objectoriginalY;
}
}
```

**Page 3**

```
    var objoriginalX:Number;
var objoriginalY:Number;

buttonMode = true;
Butter1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Butter1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
Butter2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Butter2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
Butter3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Butter3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
Butter4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Butter4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
Butter5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Butter5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

function pickupObj(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.startDrag(true);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    objoriginalX = event.target.x;
    objoriginalY = event.target.y;
}

function dropObj(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.stopDrag();
    var matchingTargetName:String = "target" + event.target.name;
    var matchingTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(matchingTargetName);
    if (event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == matchingTarget){
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = matchingTarget.x;
        event.target.y = matchingTarget.y;
    } else {
        event.target.x = objoriginalX;
        event.target.y = objoriginalY;
}
}
```

**Page4**

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
stop();

targetSqueek.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,playSqueek);
targetCat.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, playCat);
targetDog.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, playDog);


function playSqueek(event:Event){
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    var mySound:SqueekSound=new SqueekSound();
    var myChannel:SoundChannel=mySound.play();
}


function playCat(event:Event){
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    var mySound2:CatSound=new CatSound();
    var myChannel:SoundChannel=mySound2.play();
}

function playDog(event:Event){
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    var mySound1:DogSound=new DogSound();
    var myChannel:SoundChannel=mySound1.play();
}

var obj_1originalX:Number;
var obj_1originalY:Number;

buttonMode = true;
Dog.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Dog.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
Cat.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Cat.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
Squeek.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Squeek.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

function pickupObj_1(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.startDrag(true);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    obj_1originalX = event.target.x;
    obj_1originalY = event.target.y;
}

function dropObj_1(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.stopDrag();
    var matchingTargetName:String = "target" + event.target.name;
    var matchingTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(matchingTargetName);
    if (event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == matchingTarget){
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = matchingTarget.x;
        event.target.y = matchingTarget.y;
    } else {
        event.target.x = obj_1originalX;
        event.target.y = obj_1originalY;
}
}
```

this is the error that come up when I click home
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at Main/click_home()

Answer (score 0):

In looking at your code (unless there is something you omitted), I take it you are placing the  visual elements using the WYSIWYG. Removing child elements can be a pain-in-the-hiney at times. I had almost this exact same problem.

I don't know your project, but this is just an alternative approach that might make it easier. Take it if you like it, leave it if you don't...

Place all the elements for the Home screen into one MovieClip, and name it something like "Home_Screen" in your library. (Assuming Flash Professional, here. This'll be a bit different in Flash Builder.) Similarly, place all the elements for the game (or, possibly, for each level) in another MovieClip named something like "Level_One" or "Main_Game".

Now, place these MovieClips on the stage, and hook up your buttons to flip between these larger MovieClips.

The standard at my company is to have two functions on each of those screen MovieClips. One function, generally called "display()", includes the line `this.visible = true;` and calls whatever lines of code are needed to start sound, etc. The other, "hide()" includes the line `this.visible = false;`, and stops sounds, animations, whatever, to free up memory.

When your program first starts up, it should call "display()" on your home screen object, and "hide()" on all the others. Set up your buttons to use the display() and hide() functions on the screen objects.

(NOTE: You can take a similar approach if you're drawing everything via code, but as I do most things visually for the sake of my animators, this is the approach I know.)

(NOTE #2: There is a pervasive myth that it is "bad practice" to put code on the timeline. This principle is a relic from the days of AS2, and is no longer strictly relevant if you create visual elements WYSIWYG. General rule of thumb: if it directly modifies a symbol, put it on that symbol's timeline. If it is pure code, put it in a class.)